# SAPUI5 Web IDE can you use npm install?

Tags: sapui5

i have a question, can you install node pack. in the web ide? or generally use npm commands?
i want to use this [pad](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad) for example. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add a dependancy to `package.json`. When you "build" a project, it will first run `npm install`

Comment: mhm, this i tryed so far.. but where i find the dependancys? how i can add them in my controller?

Comment: the question was how to use `npm install` in WebIDE, and this is how. How to use the `pad` library, is a different question... maybe the pad documentation will help. if not, just ask a new question, how to use pad in a sapui5 app.

Comment: mhm for usually you do something like import foo from 'bar', i mean install okay but how i can import the lib in my controller and how to use it there is also no problem the documentation is very good but how i can import libs in ui5 in my controller